# Changing the Parametization option in SQL Server 2012 from Simple to Forced

Tags: sql-server-2012

Does changing the Parametization option in SQL Server 2012 from Simple to Forced clear the cache; or should DBCC FREEPROCCACHE be run after the change?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It frees the plan cache for the database that you change the option for, and nothing else.

On my server, I run these queries:

```
USE StackOverflow;

SELECT TOP 1000 * FROM dbo.Users AS u WHERE u.Reputation = 2;

USE StackOverflow2010;

SELECT TOP 1000 * FROM dbo.Users AS u WHERE u.Reputation = 1;
```

Then I use [sp_BlitzCache](http://firstresponderkit.org) to look at my plan cache:

[image: NUTS]

After that, change one database to use Forced Parameterization:

```
ALTER DATABASE StackOverflow SET PARAMETERIZATION FORCED
```

Give [sp_BlitzCache](http://firstresponderkit.org) another run:

[image: NUTS]

Only the plan from StackOverflow2010 remains.

Full disclosure: I contribute a lot of mostly working code to the open source sp_BlitzCache stored procedure.

Answer (score -2):

edit: retested with Erics comment.  Further testing showed what was expected and it does NOT keep the plan.
We can see plan in `bucketID 4969` is removed after we change the `DBAdmin` DB.

The process to verify this remains the same but i'll update the script to include the results of my test run.

**Original post:**
I just tested it and oddly enough from what I've seen it keeps the plan.  I'm going to review this further but this was my testing so far.  **I expected it to flush the results.  I'll do more testing and post but you can follow the logic here.**

On non prod server:

```
USE DBAdmin
GO
SELECT name, is_parameterization_forced FROM sys.databases
/*
name    is_parameterization_forced
master  0
tempdb  0
model   0
msdb    0
ReportServer$xxxx   0
ReportServer$xxxxTempDB 0
dbadmin_Central 0
DBAdmin 0
*/


DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
/* DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator. */
GO

SELECT * --plan_handle, query_plan, objtype   
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans   
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(plan_handle)   
GO
--26904 2   1   57344   0x000001D8BE2C6060  Compiled Plan   Adhoc   0x06000800AF0A5E2F400A98DBD801000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

select top 10 * from dbadmin.dbo.Databases
GO
--(10 row(s) affected)


SELECT * --plan_handle, query_plan, objtype   
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans   
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(plan_handle)  
GO
/*
34706   2   1   65536   0x000001D8C6D54060  Compiled Plan   Proc    0x0500050035F9F31A80D12FDBD801000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
29213   2   1   40960   0x000001D8C6D7C060  Compiled Plan   Proc    0x0500050029B1F43320CA2FDBD801000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
4969    2   1   57344   0x000001D8C6D66060  Compiled Plan   Adhoc   0x060008004ABF810AE0C82DBDD801000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
22197   2   1   40960   0x000001D8C414A060  Compiled Plan   Adhoc   0x0600080034126A2B60C12DBDD801000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
25346   2   3   253952  0x000001D8C4D9E060  Compiled Plan   Adhoc   0x06000500AACD810E401998DBD801000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
19925   2   3   147456  0x000001D8D15A8060  Compiled Plan   Adhoc   0x060005001BA31F37C01198DBD801000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
26904   2   1   57344   0x000001D8BE2C6060  Compiled Plan   Adhoc   0x06000800AF0A5E2F400A98DBD801000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
*/

ALTER DATABASE [DBAdmin] SET PARAMETERIZATION FORCED
GO



SELECT * --plan_handle, query_plan, objtype   
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans   
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(plan_handle)   
GO
/*
34706   2   1   65536   0x000001D8C6D54060  Compiled Plan   Proc    0x0500050035F9F31A80D12FDBD801000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
29213   2   1   40960   0x000001D8C6D7C060  Compiled Plan   Proc    0x0500050029B1F43320CA2FDBD801000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
26904   2   1   57344   0x000001D8CFF82060  Compiled Plan   Adhoc   0x06000800AF0A5E2F400A98DBD801000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
25346   2   6   253952  0x000001D8C4D9E060  Compiled Plan   Adhoc   0x06000500AACD810E401998DBD801000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
19925   2   6   147456  0x000001D8D15A8060  Compiled Plan   Adhoc   0x060005001BA31F37C01198DBD801000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
*/
select top 10 * from dbadmin.dbo.Databases
GO
SELECT * --plan_handle, query_plan, objtype   
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans   
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(plan_handle)  
/*
34706   2   1   65536   0x000001D8C6D54060  Compiled Plan   Proc    0x0500050035F9F31A80D12FDBD801000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
29213   2   1   40960   0x000001D8C6D7C060  Compiled Plan   Proc    0x0500050029B1F43320CA2FDBD801000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
4969    2   1   57344   0x000001D8C43D6060  Compiled Plan   Adhoc   0x060008004ABF810AE0D72DBDD801000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
32469   2   1   40960   0x000001D8CA498060  Compiled Plan   Adhoc   0x060008008F27113060D02DBDD801000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
30470   2   1   229376  0x000001D8C410A060  Compiled Plan   Adhoc   0x060001004765200BE0C82DBDD801000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
21758   2   1   327680  0x000001D8C4DF0060  Compiled Plan   Prepared    0x06000100962E9C1160C12DBDD801000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
26904   2   1   57344   0x000001D8CFF82060  Compiled Plan   Adhoc   0x06000800AF0A5E2F400A98DBD801000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
25346   2   7   253952  0x000001D8C4D9E060  Compiled Plan   Adhoc   0x06000500AACD810E401998DBD801000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
19925   2   7   147456  0x000001D8D15A8060  Compiled Plan   Adhoc   0x060005001BA31F37C01198DBD801000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
*/


USE DBAdmin
GO
SELECT name, is_parameterization_forced FROM sys.databases
/*
master  0
tempdb  0
model   0
msdb    0
ReportServer$xxxx   0
ReportServer$xxxxempDB  0
dbadmin_Central 0
DBAdmin 1
*/
```

Comment: Try running the top x query from inside the database you're changing the option on.

Comment: Hi Eric, redid the testing and you were correct!  Post is updated to show the expected results and the purged plan.  +1